# FB Api - like to show content

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, session, facebook-like

can someone please help me with fb api? I want to display content when a person clicks on the button I like it. When I click the button like so to me it appears, but when I refresh the page, so I have to click again to like. You could write something to you that the man remembered and every time they would fit on the page, so not to have to click on the like?

```
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '826612577359205',
      session : true,
      status  : true,
      cookie  : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
            window.location.reload();
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
                $('#hidden_content').show();
        });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<h1><?php echo $page['name'];?></h1>
<div id="hidden_content" style="display: none;"><?php echo $page['description']; ?></div>


<div class="block-blue" id="like" style="display: block;">
  <p>Pro zobrazení tipu je potřeba dát like na naší stránku</p>
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Betligacz-s%C3%A1zka%C5%99sk%C3%A1-liga-o-pen%C3%ADze/857630110921931?fref=ts" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: When someone logs into facebook         `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
            window.location.reload();
        });` creates a perpetual reload. If they are logged in the page just reloads, so no other code is executed below that.

Comment: You advise me what to write, so when a person presses the button like and leaving the site, so that he then turned out?

Comment: Get rid of `window.location.reload();` for starters. Are you trying to make a Facebook Web App?

Comment: I need to do it on this page. This is partly done.  http://placenetipy.cz/2014-10-30

Comment: You do know that PHP executes before the page loads into your Browser for the Client only, and that you have problems with your HTML, right?

Comment: I need to do when you can like, so that his views content, and when they leave the page or her resume, so that the content should display order. Currently I have it so that when the page is reloaded, so the content will disappear and you must click on the like again to his views content.

Comment: Yeah, the page must be reloaded to make a Cookie work. You can write code to test for the cookie.

Comment: Can you add code here for it please ?

Comment: cookies will not work, they are not reliable enough and a new user who already liked your page would still show up as "not liked". but the main point is that it´s not allowed, see my answer with the links to the facebook docs.

Comment: Here: http://www.platenetipyzdarma.sk/?p=877 It work normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible solution for this would be to authorize the user with the "`user_likes`" permission and check the like status with the Graph API. But you would need to go through a review process with that permission before anyone without a role in your App (Admin/Developer/Tester) would be able to use it and Facebook will not approved it for "Like-Gating". Also, it is not allowed to incentivize Likes anymore according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

**Meaning, you can´t do it and you are not allowed to do it.**

Comment: Can not do it over cookies?

Comment: that would be pointless (user without cookie set, but liked the page already > will still show up as not liked) - and as i said, it´s not allowed to incentivize likes anymore.

Comment: what works? if i would go to that page when i´ve already liked it, it would NOT work. and i cannot say this often enough: what you want to do is not allowed. not allowed means: don´t do it.

Comment: just to make this perfectly clear: you want to hide content behind a like button, people would need to like something to see the content. and that is not allowed. read the platform policy and the changelog in my answer. - just because you see it on some page does not mean it´s allowed. that page should get reported for not following the platform policy.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot do that.

It's on [Facebook Developer Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy)

Read **13** and **4.14**

Comment: Why not? On this page http://www.platenetipyzdarma.sk/?p=877 it works normally. When you click on like you can saw what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, but it's against their rules... (I was developing something similar)

Comment: You do not know how to do what I need?

Comment: It's possible... but not under Facebook terms... And by developing, you agree with them

Comment: It is my job http://placenetipy.cz/2014-11-13 , but when I restore the page so it disappears and you must click on the like again.

Comment: Yeah... that's not allowed =/

Comment: Yes, I know, but just as I need it to do. You do not know how to solve that problem?